# Camera preview layer does not show up Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, swift4

I am creating a ViewController in which I want to have a somewhat small UIView in the corner of the ViewController to display the camera preview. I am using a function to do this. However when I pass in the small UIView into the function the camera preview is not showing up. The weird thing is if I tell the function to display the preview on `self.view` everything works fine and I can see the camera preview. For this reason I think the problem is with the way I insert the layer or something similar.

Here is the function I am using to display the preview...

```
   func displayPreview(on view: UIView) throws {
        guard let captureSession = self.captureSession, captureSession.isRunning else { throw CameraControllerError.captureSessionIsMissing }

        self.previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        self.previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        self.previewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = .portrait

        view.layer.insertSublayer(self.previewLayer!, at: 0)

        self.previewLayer?.frame = view.frame


    }
```

I call this function from inside another function which handles setting up the capture session and other similar things.

```
    func configureCameraController() {
        cameraController.prepare {(error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("ERROR")
                print(error)
            }else{

            }
            print("hello")
            try! self.cameraController.displayPreview(on: self.mirrorView)
        }
    }

    configureCameraController()
```

How can I get the camera preview layer to show up on the smaller UIView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try adding the following

```
let rootLayer: CALayer = self.yourSmallerView.layer
rootLayer.masksToBounds = true
self.previewLayer.frame = rootLayer.bounds
rootLayer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)
```

in place of

```
view.layer.insertSublayer(self.previewLayer!, at: 0)
```

Also ensure, `yourSmallerView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleToFill`